# Prove the triangle inequality for series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove the triangle inequality for series, that is if $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely then $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n| \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n| $.

My attempy: Since $\sum x_n$ converges absolutely, it is cauchy series. Then, $\forall \varepsilon>0,$ there exists $M\in Z^+$ such that $|\sum_{j=n+1}^{k}|x_n||<\varepsilon$ for $n\ge M$ and $k>n$. Then,

$|\sum_{j=n+1}^{k}|x_n||=\sum_{j=n+1}^{k}|x_n| \ge |\sum_{j=n+1}^{k}x_n|$ by triangle inequality.

I think it is wrong since I use triangle inequality, which is required to be proven, and I also don't know how to change  $\sum_{j=n+1}^{k} \rightarrow \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}$.

Could you give some help?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Isn't the inequality the other way around?

Comment: Hint: if you have two convergent sequences $a_n$ and $b_n$ and you know $a_n\leq b_n$ for every $n$, what can you say in the limit?

Comment: this $|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n| \ge \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$ is wrong. The triangle inequality is this: $$|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n| \le \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$$ Use the algebra of limits, that is, if $\lim a_n=a$ and $\lim b_n=b$ and $a_n\le b_n$ for all $n\in\Bbb N$ then $a\le b$

Comment: Actually, $b_n$ convergent is enough

Answer (score 2):

we have

$|\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|$ by the triangle inequality wich is true for any $n \in\mathbb{N}$ so by taking $ n \rightarrow +\infty  $ you can deduce 
$|\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x_n| \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|x_n|$

Comment: The question asks to prove triangle inequality, so I think we cannot use that property.

Comment: yes we can because i use this inequality for a finite number of terms , after  the inequality is true for any $n$. so we can use the limite

Comment: The question asks to prove triangle inequality for series. You can use the standard triangle inequality

Comment: you are using that $|\sum x_j| \le \sum |x_j|$ at first. Isn't it what we want to prove?

Comment: i use this $|\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_j|\leq \sum_{j=1}^{n}|x_j|$ and this is true by the classical triangle inequality